# Query performance on primary index vs index

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have a table on mysql and two queries whose performances are quite different. I have extracted plans of the queries, but I couldn't fully understand the reason behind the performance difference.

The table:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|   TableA    |                                              |                                    |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| id          | int(10)   unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT   |                                    |
| userId      | int(10)                                      | unsigned DEFAULT NULL              |
| created     | timestamp                                    | NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| PRIMARY KEY | id                                           |                                    |
| KEY userId  | userId                                       |                                    |
| KEY created | created                                      |                                    |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Keys/Indices: The primary key on `id` field, a key on `userId` field ASC
, another key on `created` field ASC.

`tableA` is a very big table, it contains millions of rows.

The query I run on this table is:

The user with id `1234` has 1.5M records in this table. I want to fetch its latest 100 rows. In order to achieve this, I have 2 different queries:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA USE INDEX (userId) 
WHERE userId=1234 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
WHERE userId=1234 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Since `id` field of `tableA` is auto increment, the condition of being latest is preserved. These 2 queries return the same result. However, there is a huge performance difference.

Query plans are:

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Query No |                   Operation                   |            Params             | Raws |               Raw desc                |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Query 1  | Sort(using file sort) Unique index scan (ref) | table: tableA; index: userId; | 2.5M | Using index condition; Using filesort |
| Query 2  | Unique index scan (ref)                       | table: tableA; index: userId; | 2.5M | Using where                           |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+


+--------+-------------+
|        | Performance |
+--------+-------------+
| Query1 | 7,5 s       |
+--------+-------------+
| Query2 | 741 ms      |
+--------+-------------+
```

I understand that there is a sorting operation on Query 1. In each query, the index used is `userId`. But why is sorting not used in Query 2? How does the primary index affect?

Mysql 5.7

Edit: There are more columns on the table, I have extracted them from the table definition above.

Comment: You forgot to tell us which indices you created on this table already.

Comment: What is the relative performance of the two queries?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added performance data and the indices on the table.

Comment: Nothing at all surprising about the performance.  MySQL doesn't want to use the index `userId`, so when you force it, the performance degrades.  See my answer for an index which should work well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I second your warning. But I am not sure you have read my comment under the answer. If I dont explicitly say the index, then the query is timed out, it never returns. It has the worse performance. So, you can consider my question without "use index" field. The main question is still valid.

Comment: This is not what I am reading.  I see the first query with `USE INDEX` and relatively slow performance, and the second query does not force an index and performs better.  Did you post incorrectly?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The first query is ordered by "created". The second query is ordered by "id".

Comment: Anyway, before doing any speed testing, you should instruct MySQL to disable the query cache beforehand: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE …`

Comment: @emix yes I did.

Comment: Doesn't look like judging by queries from the question.

Comment: Because it does not serve the purpose. I tried to make the question as clean as possible. There are many comments on this question, but they unfortunately do not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since id field of tableA is auto increment, the condition of being latest is preserved.

That is *usually* a valid statement.

```
WHERE userId=1234 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100
```

needs this 'composite' index:  `(userId, created)`.  With that, it will hit only 100 rows, regardless of the table size or the number of rows for that user.

The same goes for

```
WHERE userId=1234 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Namely that it needs `(userId, id)`.  However, in InnoDB, when you say `INDEX(x)` it silently tacks on the `PRIMARY KEY` columns.  So you effectively get `INDEX(x,id)`.  This is why your plain `INDEX(userId)` worked well.

`EXPLAIN` rarely (if ever) takes into account the `LIMIT`.  This is why 'Rows' is "2.5M" for both queries.

The first query might (or might not) have used `INDEX(userId)` if you took out the `USE INDEX` hint.  The choice depends on what percentage of the table has `userId = 1234`.  If it is less than about 20%, the index would be used.  But it would bounce back and forth between the secondary index and the data -- all 1.5 million times.  If more than 20%, it would avoid the bouncing by simply reading all the "millions" of rows, ignoring those that don't apply.

Note:  What you had for Q1 will still read at least 1.5M rows, sort them ("Using filesort"), then peel off the desired 100.  But with `INDEX(userId, created)`, it can skip the sort and look at only 100 rows.

I cannot explain "Unique index scan" without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the un-annotated `EXPLAIN`.  (`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` might provide more insight.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is really explanatory and gives more insight. Also, to your question about number of columns on the table: Yes, there are more columns on the table. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Shnkc - Because of there being more columns in the table, plus your use of `*` (`SELECT *`), Tim's comments about "covering" do not apply.